# Unsupported config option for services while starting Sitecore with Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to install `Sitecore 10.3 XP0` using `Docker` on my windows machine.

I am following the document **Sitecore XP 10.3.0 Developer Workstation Deployment With Docker**.
After executing `compose-init.ps1`, I am running the command **docker-compose.exe up --detach**.
On the first execution, I got the following error:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'mssql'
```

On the second execution, I got the following error:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'xconnect'
```

I am using windows container.
My `docker-compose.yml` is as below:

```
services:
  traefik:
    isolation: ${TRAEFIK_ISOLATION}
    image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE}
    command:
      - "--ping"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8079:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        type: npipe
      - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_healthy
      cm:
        condition: service_healthy
  mssql:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/mssql-developer:2017-${EXTERNAL_IMAGE_TAG_SUFFIX}
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\mssql-data
        target: c:\data
  mssql-init:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      SQL_SERVER: ${SQL_SERVER}
      SQL_ADMIN_LOGIN: ${SQL_SA_LOGIN}
      SQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX: ${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}
      SQL_CUSTOM_DATABASE_PREFIX_UPDATE_FROM: ${SQL_CUSTOM_DATABASE_PREFIX_UPDATE_FROM}
      SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      POST_DEPLOYMENT_WAIT_PERIOD: 300
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "if ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('DatabasesDeploymentStatus', 'Machine') -eq 'Complete') { exit 0 } else { exit 1}"]
      start_period: 300s
      interval: 5s
    depends_on:
      mssql:
        condition: service_healthy
  solr:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/solr:8.11.2-${EXTERNAL_IMAGE_TAG_SUFFIX}
    ports:
      - "8984:8983"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\solr-data
        target: c:\data
    environment:
      SOLR_MODE: solrcloud
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "try { $$statusCode = (iwr http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS -UseBasicParsing).StatusCode; if ($$statusCode -eq 200) { exit 0 } else { exit 1} } catch { exit 1 }"]
  solr-init:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-solr-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      SITECORE_SOLR_CONNECTION_STRING: http://solr:8983/solr
      SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
    depends_on:
      solr:
        condition: service_healthy
  id:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id7:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__SitecoreMemberShipOptions__ConnectionString: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__AccountOptions__PasswordRecoveryUrl: https://${CM_HOST}/sitecore/login?rc=1
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__PasswordClient__ClientSecrets__ClientSecret1: ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${CM_HOST}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawData: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__PublicOrigin: https://${ID_HOST}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawDataPassword: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pwsh", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
    depends_on:
      mssql-init:
        condition: service_healthy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.rule=Host(`${ID_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.tls=true"
  cm:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_started
      xconnect:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Core: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Security: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Master: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Master;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Web;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.pools;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_ExperienceForms: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.ExperienceForms;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Exm.Master: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Exm.master;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Sitecore.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Cortex.Processing.Engine: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Solr.Search: http://solr:8983/solr;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SitecoreIdentity.Secret:  ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Operations.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.ReferenceData.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_GraphQL_Enabled: ${SITECORE_GRAPHQL_ENABLED}
      Sitecore_GraphQL_ExposePlayground: ${SITECORE_GRAPHQL_EXPOSEPLAYGROUND}
      Sitecore_GraphQL_UploadMediaOptions_EncryptionKey: ${SITECORE_GRAPHQL_UPLOADMEDIAOPTIONS_ENCRYPTIONKEY}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_Authority: https://${ID_HOST}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority: http://id
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_CallbackAuthority: https://${CM_HOST}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_Require_Https: "false"
      Sitecore_Analytics_Forwarded_Request_Http_Header: X-Forwarded-For
      SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
      MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET: ${MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET}
      LOG_LEVEL_VALUE: ${LOG_LEVEL_VALUE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.rule=Host(`${CM_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.middlewares=force-STS-Header"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\device-detection-data
        target: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\DeviceDetection
  xconnect:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xconnect:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      mssql-init:
        condition: service_healthy
      solr-init:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.Engine.Tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Marketingautomation;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.pools;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
  xdbsearchworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbsearchworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
  xdbautomationworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbautomationworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Marketingautomation;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
  cortexprocessingworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Processing.Engine.Tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Configuration: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Search: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
```

Comment: That can be as easy as a problem with wrong indentation. However if that's the case, it would be really hard to notice the issue within SSE post.

Comment: @MarekMusielak: Thanks for it. I checked the file in yml validators. I have not changed the file manually. So many should have got this issue. So still puzzled. Thanks for dropping by.

Comment: Have you tried adding a version to the top of the file? Noticed the deployment package for 10.1 (which is what im using) has version: "2.4" at the top. yet the 10.3 one doesnt have anything... would have thought that would still need specifying. Perhaps its defaulting to wrong version? however would have expected sitecore to pick up on that :)